# showing results from mysql according to user id?

Tags: php, mysql

Wonder if someone could help me. I have a function on my site where users can link friends, if they go on another users profile and select the 'be my friend link' then it will add and match  that user id to the database with the user who added the friend's id and the person being added as a friend's id.

now i'm trying to echo out the friends a user has on their page, at the moment the function i'm using below is echoing out a users friends to all the other users profiles.

But i want each users friends to be displayed individually so if user 1 adds user 3 4 and 5 as his friends on user 1's page it will show user 3 4 and 5.

And if user 2 adds friends 8 9 and 10 then users 8 9 and 10 will be displayed in user 2s page.

Can someone show me where i'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Function code:

```
function get_friends() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT e.friend_id, p.display_name
                        FROM ptb_friends e, ptb_profiles p
                        WHERE e.user_id = p.user_id
                        LIMIT 3";
                        $friend_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($friend_set);
            return $friend_set;
        }
```

my echo out code:

```
<?php
        $friend_set = get_friends();
while ($friend = mysql_fetch_array($friends_set)) {

    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$friend['friend_id']}\"><img width=\"60px\" height=\"60px\" class=\"friend_pic\" src=\"data/photos/{$friend['friend_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";
?>
<?
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: lol. you don't need to make `$_SESSION` `global` since its itself a superglobal array

Comment: please dont use `mysql_*` function its deprecated  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110188/is-there-a-pdo-tutorial-for-the-beginners/14110189#14110189

Answer (score 0):

in Your query you should use the ORDER-BY function

```
select e1."Event_Name", v2."Venue", e1."Ticket_price"
from "events" e1, "venues" v2
where (e1."VenueNo" = v2."VenueNo")
order by e1."Ticket_price" asc
```

// asc for ascending desc for descending

in you case

```
$query = "SELECT e.friend_id, p.display_name
                    FROM ptb_friends e, ptb_profiles p
                    WHERE e.user_id = p.user_id
                    ORDER BY e.user_id 
                    LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: in what sense? i don't care how they are ordered, i just want each own users friends to show up on their individual profile, but at the moment im getting a users friends displaying on all users profiles?

Comment: ok i see what you mean but that doesn't work. i am still geting the users friends being displayed on all users profiles.

Comment: if you are going to collect data from multiple tables and also want to view it ordered later you can use the GROUP-BY e.user_id function

Comment: ORDER-BY and GROUP-BY are ways of displaying the info . what you are trying to do is filter information . you should create a separate table for all the related friends

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a table like "added-frinds"?

Comment: surely that doesn't matter, if it's friend_id or added friends?

Answer (score 0):

To connect two tables as you do it in your query, use the [Mysql-JOIN-Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

You pass current profile user id into this page. Then apply where clause like this format where p.user_id = current_profile_user_id on your sql.So you will only get this user profile friends.(so there must be a table for satisfy this query like this format).

user_id        friends_id
--------       ---------- 
2                3

4                5

2                1

Here 2 number user profile id have friends of these ids(3,1).